# WMSLayer.getSource() Is not a function?

Tags: ajax, openlayers-3, wms

I just want to try showing information about the wms layer about the layers details using openlayers 3.14

```
map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {   
  var url = layers.getSource().getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
      evt.coordinate, viewResolution, viewProjection,
      {'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/javascript',
       'propertyName': 'formal_en'});
  if (url) {
    var parser = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      jsonpCallback: 'parseResponse'
    }).then(function(response) {
      var result = parser.readFeatures(response);
      if (result.length) {
        var info = [];
        for (var i = 0, ii = result.length; i < ii; ++i) {
          info.push(result[i].get('formal_en'));
        }
        container.innerHTML = info.join(', ');
      } else {
        container.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: where is layers defined?

Answer (score 0):

`layers` is probably an array of `ol.layer` or it may not even be available in the function's scope.

Either way you need to get a single layer to use `.getGetFeatureInfoUrl()` against.

So either something like:

```
layers[0].getSource().getGetFeature....
```

or if layers isn't available you can get it from the map object with `.getLayers()`

```
map.getLayers().forEach(function(layer) {
    // optionally check that the layer is the one you want.
    if (layer.getProperties().ref === 'myLayer'){
      layer.getSource().getGetFeature....
    }
}
```